# Check if the line contains /*

Tags: java, code-analysis, readline, block-comments

I want to check if my line contains `/*` or  not. I know how to check if the block comment is in the start:

```
/* comment starts from the beginning and ends at the end */

if(line.startsWith("/*") && line.endsWith("*/")){

      System.out.println("comment : "+line);  
}
```

What I want to know is how to figure the comment is, like this:

```
something here /* comment*/
```

or

```
something here /*comment */ something here
```

Comment: @sureshatta. There is a question. Just that it doesn't end in a `?`.

Comment: @sureshatta *What I want to know is how to figure the comment is like, this* it needs a `?` at the end, but it is a question.

Comment: do you think about using regular expressions?

Comment: "What I want to know is how to figure the comment is like, this : " is my question

Comment: Oh ,My bad ...sorry.There is a question.

Comment: I have used StringTokenizer. But it gets complicated. I am looking if there is another less complicated way to do it.

Comment: take a look to [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes and use a regexp like this: `/\\*.*\\*/`.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza : Thanx. I think it will work :)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you shoud use `@<username>` (no spaces) to send an answer in comments to other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern :

```
String data = "this is amazing /* comment */ more data ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*.*?\\*/");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Indicates match is found. Do further processing
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Comment: Comments `/* looks like this */` while your pattern doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have made appropriate changes in the code. Please verify, it should work now.

Comment: what is the package I should use to get Matcher?

Comment: Matcher and Pattern class are available in java.util.regex package.

Answer (score 2):

This works for both `// single` and multi-line `/* comments */`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//.*|/\\*((.|\\n)(?!=*/))+\\*/");
String code = " new SomeCode(); // comment \n" + " " + "/* multi\n"
        + " line \n" + " comment */\n"
        + "void function someFunction() { /* some code */ }";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

***Output**:*

```
// comment 
/* multi
 line 
 comment */
/* some code */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to this multiple ways, here is one:

Find the "/*" in your String:

```
int begin = yourstring.indexOf("/*");
```

do the same for "*/"

This will get you two Integers with which you can get the substring containing the comment:

```
String comment = yourstring.substring(begin, end);
```

Comment: What if I have `a */ string /* like this`?

Comment: you invert begin an end? I am supposing you are imposing the syntax on how the comment will look like